# api blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs

front-end: react,
back-end: node,
when the project work on local its work good but when Ι use ngrok and swap the local-url-api by ngrok api-url i see this problem:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API-URL' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. POST "API-URL" net::ERR_FAILED

in node js Ι use cors

```
app.use(cors({
     origin: "*" ,
     credentials: true,
     optionSuccessStatus: 200
}));
```

Comment: Make sure to have your `app.use(cors` middleware before registering your routes (before `app.get()` and `app.use('/', ..)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS error but only on POST request, despite cors config (GET have no issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374111/cors-error-but-only-on-post-request-despite-cors-config-get-have-no-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this :

**Installation**

```
$ npm install cors
```

then call it from your **index.js** file :

```
// Simple Usage (Enable All CORS Requests)
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: i use cors and also i see the error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe

Comment: check the link , hopefully find there solution