# CORS problem with GET request in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, cors

I use `ASP.Net Core Web Api` as backend service in my application.

On frontend I use `React` with `axios` requests to backend api like this:

```
export const overviewGet = (orderId: string): Promise<IOrder> => {
  const URL = `http://{myhost}/orders/overview&id=${orderId}`
  return axios
    .get(URL)
    .then((d: AxiosResponse<IOrder>) => d.data) 
}

export const overviewPost = (orderId: string): Promise<IOrder> => {
  const URL = `http://{myhost}/orders/overview&id=${orderId}`
  return axios
    .post(URL)
    .then((d: AxiosResponse<IOrder>) => d.data) 
}
```

In `Program.cs` on backend I add `CORS` default policy to accept requests from frontend.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                ;
    });
});
```

Then in my Controller I've created 2 methods with `Get` and `Post` requests

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class OrdersController: ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("overview")]
    public IActionResult Overview(Guid id) => Ok();

    [HttpPost("overview")]
    public IActionResult Overview1(Guid id) => Ok();
}
```

When I call `overviewPost` method in frontend, there's success response.
But when I call `overviewGet` method, there's `CORS` error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://{myhost}/orders/overview?id=08da602c-5b76-4f3b-822d-e2c45f05c8ae' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

What am I doing wrong when I use `GET` method?

Comment: Did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374111/cors-error-but-only-on-post-request-despite-cors-config-get-have-no-issue

Comment: You might need `.UseCors()` between `UseRouting()` and `UseEndpoints()`

Comment: `{myhost}` needs to be `localhost:3000`.  I assume you're trying to use a javascript template in which case the string should be  ``http://${myhost}/orders/overview&id=${orderId}``

Comment: I tested with`app.UseCors();`, both get and post works.

Answer (score 0):

/*Startup.cs*/

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)
{
    service.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .SetIsOriginAllowed(host => true)
                   .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
}
```