# CORS error - I have set the headers but I keep getting the same error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cors-anywhere

I have an API in Node.js - TypeScript using cors:

```
import cors from 'cors';

const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Origin',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'Content-Type',
    'Accept',
    'X-Access-Token',
    'access-control-allow-origin',
  ],
  credentials: true,
  preflightContinue: false,
};

app.use(cors(options));
app.options('*', cors(options));
```

And a react app using axios:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './Login.css'

const Login = () => {
    const [ email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [ password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        if(email !== '' && password !== ''){
            await axios.post('http://localhost:3003/allProducts', {Id: 1}).then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='login'>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="email" placeholder='Email' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                <input type="password" placeholder='Password' onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                <button type='button' onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
            </form>
            <p>Don't have an account yet?<span>Sign in.</span></p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Why am I receiving this CORS error if I have set the headers at the API and have tried A million of things at the Internet but I keep receiving the same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p82EI.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In the network tab, what does the response to the `OPTIONS` request look like? According to the error, it doesn't have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. (Side note: `allowedHeaders` in [`cors.CorsOptions`](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options) is what **request** headers are allowed. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a *response* header, you shouldn't list it there.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS error but only on POST request, despite cors config (GET have no issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374111/cors-error-but-only-on-post-request-despite-cors-config-get-have-no-issue)

Answer (score 0):

**Note: keep in mind that disabling `CORS` on `production` applications is not secure.**

Try to update the CORS `options` because you may be omitting some of the allowed headers.

```
import cors from 'cors';

const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};

app.use(cors(options));
```

In addition the whole `cors` usage in your `Node.js` application could be simplified by not passing `options` object (if you are currently only testing things out in **development**) and falling back to `default` settings which will enable content for all `origins`.

```
import cors from 'cors';

app.use(cors());
```